# Rails 4, nested attributes, strong parameters & JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, strong-parameters

Rails 4, basic JSON API - I am tying to update Status object with association Position objects.

Job Status model:

```
class JobStatus < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :job
    has_many :positions

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :positions, limit: 1

    validates :job_id,
                    :slug,
                    presence: true

end
```

Position Model:

```
class Position < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :agent
  belongs_to :job_status

  validates :job_status_id,
                    :agent_id,
                    :lat,
                    :lng,
                    presence: true

end
```

Job Statuses Controller:

```
class Api::V1::Jobs::JobStatusesController < ApplicationController

    wrap_parameters format: [:json]

    def create

        @status = JobStatus.new(status_params)

        @status.job_id = params[:job_id]

        @status.positions.build

        if @status.save
            render :json => {status: 'success', saved_status: @status}.to_json
        else
            render :json => {status: 'failure', errors: @status.errors}.to_json
        end

    end

    private

        def status_params
            params.permit(:job_id, :slug, :notes, :positions_attributes => [:lat, :lng, :job_status_id, :agent_id])
        end

end
```

This is the JSON I am posting:

```
{
  "slug":"started",
  "notes":"this xyz notes",
  "positions_attributes":[{
    "lat" : "-72.348596",
    "lng":"42.983456"
  }]
}
```

When I do "logger.warn params" immediately above the @status.positions.build:

```
{"slug"=>"started", "notes"=>"this xyz notes", "positions_attributes"=>[{"lat"=>"-72.348596", "lng"=>"42.983456"}], "action"=>"create", "controller"=>"api/v1/jobs/job_statuses", "job_id"=>"3", "job_status"=>{"slug"=>"started", "notes"=>"this xyz notes"}}
```

And the error message that gets returned to me:

```
{
"status":"failure",
"errors":{
"positions.job_status_id":[
"can't be blank"
],
"positions.agent_id":[
"can't be blank"
],
"positions.lat":[
"can't be blank"
],
"positions.lng":[
"can't be blank"
]
}
```

So I'm not really sure where my problem is - are my strong parameters not allowed correctly? Should I be posting an array of positions because it's a has_many relationship, even though I only want to create one at a time? Am I not using .build correctly? I've playing monkeying around with all of these, but not luck - I'm pretty sure there's something obvious I am just not seeing.

Also, if anyone has a way to log output the data from wherever the problem is coming from, that would be v. helpful in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is this line:

```
@status.positions.build
```

This is only required in the `new` method to build HTML form, which is obviously not applicable in this case. This method is actually blanking out all `position` parameters that you are posting.

Removing this line will fix your issue.